# ERROR: error pushing image "us.gcr.io/***/appengine/default.20160429t095907:latest": exit status 1

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently created a Node.js app at Google Cloud Platform. I tested the app thoroughly at both my local environment and Cloud Shell without problem. However, every time I tried to deploy the app to App Engine, it just failed with the following error message:

> PUSH
>   The push refers to a repository [us.gcr.io/hisella-authentication/appengine/default.20160429t095907] (len: 1)
>   31185f371dc8: Preparing
>   Post https://us.gcr.io/v2/hisella-authentication/appengine/default.20160429t095907/blobs/uploads/: token auth attempt for registry: https://us.gcr.io/v2/token?account=_token&scope=repository%3Ahisella-authentication%2Fappengine%2Fdefault.20160429t095907%3Apush%2Cpull&service=us.gcr.io request failed with status: 400 Bad Request
>   ERROR
>   ERROR: error pushing image "us.gcr.io/hisella-authentication/appengine/default.20160429t095907:latest": exit status 1
>   ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details

The build logs only have the following information:

```
09:53:24.560 {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"appengine-admin-noreply@google.com"},"serviceName":"appengine.googleapis.com","methodName":"com.google.appengine.legacy.vm_administrative_task_failed","resourceName":"apps/hisella-authentication/modules/default/versions/20160427t115216","serviceData":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.legacy.AuditData","eventMessage":"VM administrative task failed.","eventData":{"module_id":"default","version":"20160427t115216.392380903859978721","version_id":"20160427t115216"}}}
{
    metadata: {
        severity: "NOTICE"
        projectId: "***"
        serviceName: "appengine.googleapis.com"
        zone: "global"
        labels: {
            appengine.googleapis.com/module_id: "default"
            appengine.googleapis.com/version_id: "20160427t115216"
        }
        timestamp: "2016-04-29T02:53:24.560Z"
        projectNumber: "***"
    }
    protoPayload: {
        @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
        authenticationInfo: {
            principalEmail: "appengine-admin-noreply@google.com"
        }
        serviceName: "appengine.googleapis.com"
        methodName: "com.google.appengine.legacy.vm_administrative_task_failed"
        resourceName: "apps/hisella-authentication/modules/default/versions/20160427t115216"
        serviceData: {
            @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.legacy.AuditData"
            eventMessage: "VM administrative task failed."
            eventData: {
                module_id: "default"
                version: "20160427t115216.392380903859978721"
                version_id: "20160427t115216"
            }
        }
    }
    insertId: "53196BF1A0068.AD6A8C5.B30E5526"
    log: "cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity"
}
```

Please help me to by-pass this problem so I can deploy my app to App Engine.

Any response from you will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 10):

The problem occurred because Google had temporarily suspended use of my APIs billing account. I have to re-verify my account information to solve the problem.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. :)

Comment: Nice! i was searching this error over the net but the solution was very simple THANK YOU!

Comment: This ended my 4hrs of agony.